# How to make my Outlook 2007 add-in trusted

Tags: c#, vsto, office-2007, .net

I have a C#.NET Outlook 2007 add-in that has to access the address book to accomplish various tasks.  However, every time on of these tasks has to access the address book I get the following warning dialog:

```
A program is trying to access e-mail address information
stored in Outlook.  If this is unexpected, click Deny and verify
your antivirus software is up-to-date.
```

Is there some way to have Outlook remember that my add-in isn't malware?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give the VSTO addin full trust using caspol.exe

You can make this signing process part of your installer.

Here is the documentation for the [Code Access Security Policy tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb6t8dtz%28VS.80%29.aspx)

The command in your installer project would look like:

```
caspol -u -ag All_Code -url "{The assembly’s full path}" FullTrust -n "{The code group name}".
```

Here are two article that details the windows installer steps for VSTO deployment

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332051.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332052.aspx

Comment: You are a rock star.  Thank you kindly for sharing your wisdom.